# import csv to R - numeric values still read as factors

Tags: r, csv, numeric

Im trying to get a column that is read as factor to be read or transformed as number. All the advices with "stringAsFactors=FALSE" or "as.numeric" do not work as expected. (See attached code)

The data.csv is a simple example that shows no strange special characters in Notepad++ and EmEditor. There is just one systematic error in "Temp" (row 5) and one in "rH" (row 4).

```
> fTimeSeries<- read.csv2('data.csv', header = TRUE, sep=";", dec=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> head(fTimeSeries)
  Station          DatumZeit   Temp    rH      Tp      Ld
1     526   02.11.2010 08:36   15,9    58.4    7.7     991.1
2     526   02.11.2010 08:38   15,6    58.8    7.6     991.3
3     526   02.11.2010 08:40   14,9    60.8    7.4     991.1
4     526   02.11.2010 08:42   14,3      NA    7.4     991.4
5     526   02.11.2010 08:44    aaa    64.2    7.5     991.3
6     526   02.11.2010 08:46   14,2    64.9    7.7     991.2

> fTimeSeries[,3]
 [1] "15,9" "15,6" "14,9" "14,3" "aaa"  "14,2" "14,2" "13,9" "13,9" "13,6" "13,6" "13,6" "13,4" "13,4" "13,7" "13,8" "13,9" "14,1" "14,3" "14,4" "14,5" "14,2" "14,2" "14,1" "14,1" "14,2"
[27] "14,1" "14,1" "14"   "14"   "14,1" "14"   "13,9" "13,9" "14"   "14"   "13,9" "14"   "14,1" "14,2" "14,2" "14,2" "14,2" "14,2" "14,2" "14,2" "14,2"
```

In column 3 "Temp" I would expect to get numbers and in row 5 instead of "aaa" an NA.

So I tried to convert it:

```
fTimeSeries[,3] <- as.numeric(fTimeSeries[,3], dec=',')
Warnmeldung:
NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 14 14 NA 14 NA NA 14 14 NA 14 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

But without success. as.numeric seems to just convert numbers without decimal separator even if I tell what the decimal separator is. (I also tried without the option dec="," without success.)

Finally I tried to get the levels as suggested in some answers here:

```
> levels(fTimeSeries$Temp)
NULL

> levels(fTimeSeries[,3])
NULL

> levels(fTimeSeries)
NULL

> levels(fTimeSeries$rH)
NULL

> head(fTimeSeries)
  Station          DatumZeit   Temp    rH      Tp      Ld
1     526   02.11.2010 08:36     NA    58.4    7.7     991.1
2     526   02.11.2010 08:38     NA    58.8    7.6     991.3
3     526   02.11.2010 08:40     NA    60.8    7.4     991.1
4     526   02.11.2010 08:42     NA      NA    7.4     991.4
5     526   02.11.2010 08:44     NA    64.2    7.5     991.3
6     526   02.11.2010 08:46     NA    64.9    7.7     991.2
```

I'm using R in a Windows7 64Bit environment

Comment: You can try to use the `colClasses` argument in `read.csv2`.

Comment: What is `aaa` in `Temp`? If it's something that can be ignored, try specifying all `NA` strings in your file (something along the lines of `na.strings = c("NA", "aaa")`) in `read.csv2`.

Comment: i don't think any of the major file reading functions can currently handle numeric types with two different possible decimal points.  @AndriyTkach probably provided the easiest solution.  read it all in somehow, then coerce as necessary  :/

Comment: If you have it open in Notepad++ already you should make use of find/replace.

Comment: Hi, thank you. In the  original data.csv there is just one kind of decimal separator ",". In the output it just shows that Temp is not correctly recognized as number, and thatfor is displayed as "15,9" ... while the correctly recognized nubers are displayed with a "." decimal separator.

Comment: So the problem is NOT, that there are different decimal separators in the original file!

Comment: @Roman and Roland: "aaa" is any faulty string in a test file. The original data.csv has about 10Mio. lines. Maybe there is a faulty string somewhere inside. I don't know and I dont't get it by means of the "levels" command.

Answer (score 0):

This one works with my simulated data. `df$x` is a factor

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("12,1","aa","15,6",61))

as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", as.character(df$x)))

# [1] 12.1   NA 15.6 61.0
```

**UPDATE with your example:**

Your Data:

```
> fTimeSeries<- read.csv2('data.csv', header = TRUE, sep=";", dec=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> head(fTimeSeries)
  Station        DatumZeit Temp   rH  Tp    Ld
1     526 02.11.2010 08:36 15,9 58.4 7.7 991.1
2     526 02.11.2010 08:38 15,6 58.8 7.6 991.3
3     526 02.11.2010 08:40 14,9 60.8 7.4 991.1
4     526 02.11.2010 08:42 14,3 <NA> 7.4 991.4
5     526 02.11.2010 08:44  aaa 64.2 7.5 991.3
6     526 02.11.2010 08:46 14,2 64.9 7.7 991.2
```

Column that not recognize:

```
> class(fTimeSeries$Temp)
[1] "character"
```

Apply my solution:

```
> fTimeSeries$Temp <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", as.character(fTimeSeries$Temp)))
> class(fTimeSeries$Temp)
[1] "numeric"
```

And your data.frame becomes:

```
> fTimeSeries
  Station        DatumZeit Temp   rH  Tp    Ld
1     526 02.11.2010 08:36 15.9 58.4 7.7 991.1
2     526 02.11.2010 08:38 15.6 58.8 7.6 991.3
3     526 02.11.2010 08:40 14.9 60.8 7.4 991.1
4     526 02.11.2010 08:42 14.3 <NA> 7.4 991.4
5     526 02.11.2010 08:44   NA 64.2 7.5 991.3
6     526 02.11.2010 08:46 14.2 64.9 7.7 991.2
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is not caused by different decimal separators in the original file. In the original file there are just "," as decimal separators. Nevertheless: Maybe you want to change your example to: df<-data.frame(x=c("12.1","aa","15,6",61)) - the first decimal separator is a "." instead of an ","

Comment: It still working if I change. My code means that first of all you convert your column to character. Then you substitute "," with "." becouse it is a decimal separator for R. And then as.numeric function works well, putting NA where there are characters and recognizing string (i.e. "12.1") as number 12.1

Comment: Of course is it still working. The example would just be clearer as it then shows that your method can handle all 4 cases. But unfortunately not for me.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. My problem is NOT that there are different decimal separators in the original file. They are all well defined with ",".

Comment: See update. I think this is a solution to your question. If you have another problem tell me

Comment: I tried your solution. On my 10Mio. lines data record it worked for over 3 hours before I terminated the experiment. I now found a solution as I found the false string in my 10Mio. lines data record and removed it. But I still wonder why stringsAsFactors option didn't work like described.

Comment: as I know, `stringsAsFactors` converts or not a character column to factor. By default a lot of data.frame functions transform character columns into a factor